# How to pass the value of a component up to its parent?

Tags: javascript, components, parent, svelte, svelte-3

I want to bind the value of a select element in a Svelte component (Form.svelte) to the variable `active` in its parent (App.svelte). I've tried using `bind:value={active}` on the Form component in App, but this doesn't work because I need to access the select's value. How should I access the value of the select element? Thanks in advance.

Minimum working example: https://svelte.dev/repl/bc872132e21f4071abe5a255728fb0ec?version=3.43.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to expose the `value` property if you want to bind to it. Here, we also bind the `value` property to the `select` element so that it is updated with changes to the select.

```
/* Select.svelte */

<script>
    export let value
</script>

<select bind:value>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

You can then bind to it in your parent

```
/* App.svelte */

<script>
    import Select from './Select.svelte'
    
    let active;
</script>

<Select bind:value={active}/>

<p>{active}</p>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e77f6a41f9f2486e962fba55cafeab95?version=3.43.0)